# Variables not updating in the main loop as intended

Tags: atmega328p

First I want to say that English is not my first language so there going to be some grammatical errors.

That said, I'm developing a simple application for the ATmega328P microprocessor where I sample two analog signals and send them to a computer using the UART.

The problem is that because this microprocesor only has one ADC I am forced to first sample one signal and then the other one. For this purpose I use a variable called **samples_obtained** to know when I have sampled two times and then I save then in the variables signal1 or signal2 and send them to the computer using the UART.

I am using a variable called canal to switch between the two inputs channels of the ADC in order to sample the two signals. This is performed because I first sample one signal and then switch the ADC channel updating the variable canal and using the function **select_adc_channel**, so when the variable **canal** is equal to 0 I sample the signal present in the ADC channel 0 and when its equal to 1 I sample the signal present in the ADC channel 1.

When **samples_obtained** is equal to 2, it means I have sampled the two signals and they are ready to be sent. The variable ADC_finished is like a flag variable that let me know when the ADC finished, thats why it is updated inside the ADC interrupt.

The problem here is that it seems like **samples_obtained** never goes up to 2, so the UART never sends anything, and it is the same with **canal**, it never goes up to 1.

```
#define F_CPU 16000000L
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

float signal1;
float signal2;

void Config_ADC(void);
void select_adc_channel(void);
void Config_Timer(void);
void SendDataUART(float, float);
void Config_UART(void);
int intToStr(int,char[],int);
void float2string(float, char*, int);

char buffer_signal1[10] = "";
char buffer_signal2[10] = "";
char string_to_print[23] = "";

volatile int canal;
int samples_obtained;
volatile int ADC_finished;
int main(void)
{
    signal1 = 0.f;
    signal2 = 0.f;
    canal=0;
    samples_obtained=0;
    ADC_finished = 0;
    Config_Timer();
    Config_ADC();
    select_adc_channel();
    Config_UART();
    sei();
    DDRB = (1<<PORTB1)|(1<<PORTB5);
    while(1)
    {
        if(ADC_finished){
            samples_obtained = samples_obtained+1;
            ADC_finished = 0;
            if(canal == 0){
                canal=1;
                signal1 = ADC*5.0f/1024.0f;
            }else{
                canal = 0;
                signal2 = ADC*5.0f/1024.0f;
            }
            select_adc_channel();
            if(samples_obtained>=2){
                SendDataUART(signal1,signal2);
                samples_obtained=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
ISR(ADC_vect){
    ADC_finished=1;
    return;
}
void Config_ADC(void){
    ADCSRA = (1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADATE)|(1<<ADPS2)|(1<<ADPS1)|(1<<ADPS0)|(1<<ADIE);
    ADCSRB = (1<<ADTS2)|(1<<ADTS0);
    DIDR0 = (1<<ADC0D)|(1<<ADC1D);
    return;
}
void select_adc_channel(void){
    if(canal==0){
        ADMUX = (0<<ADLAR)|(1<<REFS0)|(0<<MUX0)|(0<<MUX1)|(0<<MUX2)|(0<<MUX3);
    }
    else
    {
        ADMUX = (0<<ADLAR)|(1<<REFS0)|(1<<MUX0)|(0<<MUX1)|(0<<MUX2)|(0<<MUX3);
    }
    return;
}

void Config_Timer(void){
    TCCR1A = (1<<COM1A0)|(1<<COM1B0);
    TCCR1B = (1<<WGM12)|(1<<CS11)|(1<<CS10)|(0<<CS12);
    TIMSK1 = (1<<OCIE1A)|(1<<OCIE1B);
    OCR1A = 31249;
    OCR1B = 31249;
    return;
}

void Config_UART(void){
    UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ00)|(1<<UCSZ01);
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXCIE0)|(1<<TXCIE0)|(1<<TXEN0)|(1<<RXEN0);
    UCSR0A = (1<<U2X0);
    UBRR0 =(F_CPU/8/9600)-1;
    return;
}
```

The method used to send the information using the UART is:

```
void SendDataUART(float signal1, float signal2){
    char output[23] = "";
    float2string(signal1,buffer_signal1,2);
    float2string(signal2,buffer_signal2,2);
    
    strcpy(output, buffer_signal1);
    strcat(output, ";");
    strcat(output, buffer_signal2);
    strcat(output, "\r");
    for(int i=0;i<23;i++){
        while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)));
        UDR0 = output[i];
    }
    return;
}
```

The methods intToStr and float2string are just being used to convert the float numbers into strings

```
void reverse(char* str, int len)
{
    int i = 0, j = len - 1, temp;
    while (i < j) {
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

int intToStr(int x, char str[], int d)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (x) {
        str[i++] = (x % 10) + '0';
        x = x / 10;
    }
    
    // If number of digits required is more, then
    // add 0s at the beginning
    while (i < d)
    str[i++] = '0';
    
    reverse(str, i);
    str[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

// Converts a floating-point/double number to a string.
void float2string(float n, char* res, int afterpoint)
{
    // Extract integer part
    int ipart = (int)n;
    
    // Extract floating part
    float fpart = n - (float)ipart;
    
    // convert integer part to string
    int i = intToStr(ipart, res, 0);
    
    // check for display option after point
    if (afterpoint != 0) {
        res[i] = '.'; // add dot
        
        // Get the value of fraction part upto given no.
        // of points after dot. The third parameter
        // is needed to handle cases like 233.007
        fpart = fpart * pow(10, afterpoint);
        
        intToStr((int)fpart, res + i + 1, afterpoint);
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is there is an issue with your configuration of the ADC and it's never calling your ISR.

Comment: I tried sending a one through the UART when the condition (ADC_finished==1) was true and it indeed sended a bunch of ones, demostrating that indeed the interrupt is working.

Comment: A minimum example that showed the problem would help. Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the ADC but the Timer1.

The code sets Timer1 compare match B as the ADC trigger source, which is fine.

However code enables Timer1 OCIE1A and OCIE1B interrupts, but does not define interrupt handlers to these, so the default handler jumps to reset vector, and code starts from main again.

It explains why the first conversion completes and you get one ADC interrupt, as the code restarts before second ADC interrupt.

And the reason you get one ADC interrupt is that you start the ADC in free running mode before configuring the Timer1  OC1B as the trigger source.

You would have seen this restart if you had printed a "Hello I just booted" kind of banner as soon as UART is configured. Which also means important peripherals like UART should be initialized before you initialize stuff that can cause a reset if they are not right.

It is also worth single stepping the code in a simulator, the AVR Studio IDE provided this feature over 15 years ago already.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thank you so much and i didnt even know that you could do a simulation in AVR Studio (My college teacher didnt teach about that tool)